# how to connect remote ms-sql database using jsp

Tags: java, sql-server, jsp

Hello i have mssql database in Remote place system and now,i want to connect that database in my jsp page.i am knew in mssql , so kindlly help me how to connect remote place MSSQL database with jsp. i try following code. is there any things missing? to connect jsp page with mssql? thank you in advance

```
    try{

            SQLServerDataSource ds = new SQLServerDataSource();
            ds.setUser("user");
            ds.setPassword("****");
            ds.setServerName("SERVER-NAME");
            ds.setPortNumber(port); 
            ds.setDatabaseName("DB");
            Connection con = ds.getConnection();



     }
     catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfex)
      {
out.println(cnfex.toString());
cnfex.printStackTrace();
     }
```

This is Edited code. so kindlly help. how to finish this stuff.

Comment: your code shows that you are using mysql database but your text shows that you are using ms sql server.Be clear.rolled back to original post

Comment: i want to connect my file to ms sql

Comment: which authentication are you using windows or sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");  
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://HOSP_SQL1.ad.uams.edu;user=WebClinicalResearch;password=w3c1re$h;database=ClinicalResearch");
        System.out.println("test");
        Statement sta = conn.createStatement();
        String Sql = "select * from testing_table";
        ResultSet rs = sta.executeQuery(Sql);
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString("txt_title"));
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE :**

Look Here I have used this method to access remote data in mysql and works fine :

```
String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String dburl = "jdbc:mysql://sql4.freemysqlhosting.net:3306/DBNAME";
```

Very Good Link Here.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428.aspx
Just Check it once.